# Get all entities pointing to the same foreign key reference in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 model classes as follows:

```
public class Bill
{
    [Key]
    public int BillId { get; set; }
    public string BillNumber { get; set; }
    public string BillStatus { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public class FuelExpense
{
    [Key]
    public int FuelExpenseId {get; set; }
    public string Vehicle { get; set; }
    public FuelTypesEnum FuelType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Bill")]
    public int BillId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }
}

public class BooksAndNotesExpense
{
    [Key]
    public int BooksAndNotesExpenseId { get; set; }
    public string Publication { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Bill")]
    public int BillId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }
}
```

I want to fetch all pending bills with their respective expense id. For example my tables look like below:

[image: Bills table]

[image: FuelExpenses table]

[image: BooksAndNotesExpenses table]

I want a result like this:

[image: Result table]

How to get it in Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC using C# ? If there is a better way to re-structure my models, please let me know too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you want the answer? Raw SQL, EF extension methods, LinqToSQL?

Comment: LinqToSQL would be great. But EF extension methods will also do.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about Entity FrameWork But it looks like basic linq can do

```
var data =
dbContext.FuelExpense.Where(x => x.Bill.BillStatus == 'Pending')
.Select(x => new Data(x.BillId, x.Bill.BillNumber, x.Bill.BillStatus, x.Bill.Amount, x.FuelExpenseId))
.Concat(
dbContext.BooksAndNotesExpense.Where(x => x.Bill.BillStatus == 'Pending')
.Select(x => new Data(x.BillId, x.Bill.BillNumber, x.Bill.BillStatus, x.Bill.Amount, x.BooksAndNotesExpenseId))
)
.ToList()
```

OR

```
var data = 
dbContext.BooksAndNotesExpense
  .Join(
    dbContext.Bill,
    booksExpense => booksExpense.BillId,
    bill => bill.BillId,
    (booksExpense , bill) => new Data(bill.BillId, bill.BillNumber, bill.BillStatus, bill.Amount, booksExpense.FuelExpenseId)
  )
  .Where(x => BillStatus == 'Pending')
  .Concat(
    dbContext.FuelExpense
    .Join(
      dbContext.Bill,
      fuelExpense => fuelExpense.BillId,
      bill => bill.BillId,
      (fuelExpense, bill) => new Data(bill.BillId, bill.BillNumber, bill.BillStatus, bill.Amount, fuelExpense.BooksAndNotesExpenseId)
    )
    .Where(x => BillStatus == 'Pending')
)
.ToList()
```

```
public class Data {
  public Data(int billId, string billNumber, string billStatus, int amount, int expenseId) {
   BillId = billId;
   BillNumber = billNumber;
   BillStatus = billStatus;
   Amount = amount;
   ExpenseId = expenseId;
  }
  public int BillId { get ; set; }
  public string BillNumber { get ; set; }
  public string BillStatus { get ; set; }
  public int Amount { get ; set; }
  public int ExpenseId { get ; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nafis for the answer. It helps!